# How to create an API for any of the website?

Tags: java, javascript, facebook, api

I actually want to ask that what is the way to create an API for sites such as Facebook.. Twitter etc. I am an IT Graduate and do know programming but still wonder that how do people start to create their own set of API's for such websites. And Everyday people have a new API to access the site. Can someone throw light on the standard process that is being followed so as to achieve this ?

Comment: What do you mean by "API" exactly in this context? Can you clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no unique canonical way for the design of a public web API. You could find best practices through.

This will also depend of the complexity of what you want to expose.

Basically you'll want it to operate over standard HTTP and be accessible both by backend systems and by browser client. So you'll choose either XML or JSON as the dataformat as it is supported by everybody.

A common pratice would be to adhere to the REST architecture, but this is only one choice over many. Today REST is a buzz word. So many tend to use it even if not really suited to their needs.

Like any public API, you should take great care of backward compatibility and futureproof design. The whole refactoring thing can be thrown away as you can't break client code when developping new features. A classical way to deal with this is to publish API per version and let the client stick with the version it support.

Comment: That means if I know the REST api provided by the website as in the portal. Then I can use those url's as the base of my API which I want to design. This will be the base of my public API for that website in which ever language I want to design that in. right??

Answer (score 1):

Check [Spring Social](http://www.springsource.org/spring-social). It is a framework to write api to connect to social networking websites. Also for doing that you need to have knowledge of **OAuth** protocol which is one of the protocols used to allow access to private information with other websites.

Comment: I did take a look at it but what I want to ask is that do these websites open or provide developers some kind of interfaces so as to develop upon it??

Comment: Yes, that is only way, you can access the information available with them. See [Facebook Developer Page](https://developers.facebook.com/) for facebook api. You can find similar for other social networking websites. Search google for some sample code. Spring Social provides templates around these APIs to help you with development.